# What is the best way to change type of widget on-the-fly?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I need to show different information at the same place depending on user's actions.

For example, if one button was pressed, I need to show QTableWidget, if another button was pressed, I need to show QListWidget on the same place.

What is the simple and good way to do that thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is called [QStackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html). Fill it with necessary widgets and use.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the existing widget, create the new one, and add it to the layout in the same place.  Or create both widgets but only `show()` one and `hide()` the other.